# why there are block,controller, model directories in magento module?

Tags: magento-1.9, mvc

Can anyone explain why should we write our code in different directories while creating module? Can't we just write our block code in controller? if we put our model,block files in controller .will module work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes , it will work. But it is not a proper way. Since we are using MVC flow , we need to do in proper manner. Main purpose of doing this is re-usability.